# Tree structure data in HSQLDB

Tags: oracle, hsqldb

In my project, I need to maintain data in tree hierarchy.

Below code is something which I can do in Oracle.

Can the same be done in HSQLDB?

`create table corporate_slaves (
       slave_id           integer primary key,
       supervisor_id          references corporate_slaves,
       name           varchar(100)
);`

If I use the same code, I get `"Unexpected token: REFERENCES, error code: -5581"` in HSQLDB.

Can anyone suggest how to build this kind of table?

Regards,

Satya

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
create table corporate_slaves (
  slave_id integer primary key,
  supervisor_id integer,
  name varchar(100),
  foreign key (supervisor_id) references corporate_slaves(slave_id)
);
```

Comment: I tried that too earlier but inserting data doesnot work since the table has foreignkey reference and at data insertion time the ID will be null and its generated by a sequence

Comment: Can you correct the question? I'm using similar tables and have no troubles